# php drop downlist with 2 values the 2nd value post to hidden field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've got a regular drop downlist for selecting the countries name as text and countries_id as value.
Example:

```
<option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
```

Now I need an hidden form field with the ISO2 code for the country.
Example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="iso2" id="inputIso2" class="form-control">
```

And when the country is changed by the drop downlist, the hidden field should also change.
I've added the ISO2 to the option like this:

```
<option value="1" data-iso2="AF">Afghanistan</option>
```

But how do I pass it to the hidden field?
Or is there a better way of doing this?

The ISO2 field is being used by another script in the form, so it should work pre post.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a PHP problem so much as it is a javascript problem. You need to put an event listener on your select element and when it changes, grab data-iso2 and apply the value to the hidden field.

Using jQuery, you'd do this:

```
$("#country").change(function(){
   var iso2 = $(this).find(':selected').data('iso2');
   $("#inputIso2").val(iso2);

});
```

Comment: need data attribute of option: `var iso2 = $(this).find(':selected').data('iso2');`